# Create a wrapper around specified number of fields in views

Tags: views

I like to wrap 3 elements of a view in a div.
I got this code, but it doesn't seem to work. It keeps printing the div but never the /div which makes everything nested in the previous row.

```
<?php if($i % 3 == 0){ print '<div class="row">'; } ?>
<?php print $row; ?>
<?php if($i % 3 == 2){ print '</div>'; } ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module will let you configure HTML output easily.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if($i % 3 == 0){ print '<div class="row">'; } ?>
<?php print $row; ?>
<?php if($i % 3 == 2){ print '</div>'; } ?>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

I forgot to define $i before foreach en $i++ before endforeach.